# How to unlink file symlinked to itself without destroying

Tags: linux, files, symlink

I'm not sure how this happened, but I have a number of files that have becomed symlinked to themselves. It seems likely that there won't be any way to restore the files, but hopefully there is. Here is what ls -l says

```
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 bob users   50 Sep  9 21:45 background.png -> /path/to/background.png
```

I tried unlinking one of the files, but unfortunately the file disappeared. I've also tried readlink. Readlink says that the path to the file is /path/to/background.png

Like I said, I really don't know how this happened. I am inheriting all these files from a previous admin. Is there any recourse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a file *is* symlinked to itself then there's no data present and any attempt to access it will result in a loop, and ultimately an error

eg

```
$ ls -l myfile 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sweh sweh 19 Sep  9 22:38 myfile -> /path/to/here/myfile

$ cat myfile 
cat: myfile: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Since there's no data, deleting these symlinks won't lose any data, because there *is* no data to preserve.

If you don't get the `Too many levels of symbolic links` error when you try to `cat` the file then your file is *not* a link to itself.

Answer (score 3):

`ln` will **never** overwrite a file with a link to itself.  You can get a file linked to itself with:

```
$ ln -s `pwd`/myfile myfile
$ ls -l myfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 grochmal users 25 Sep 10 03:41 myfile -> /home/grochmal/tmp/myfile
```

But if you try with a file that contains data:

```
$ rm -f myfile
$ echo yay > myfile
$ ln -sf `pwd`/myfile myfile
ln: '/home/grochmal/tmp/myfile' and 'myfile' are the same file
```

---

`ln`, on the other hand, will overwrite a file with a link to another file.

Yet, you can be rather sure that a link to itself is a file that never ever had data (or was explicitly deleted before the creation of the soft link).

(on Linux and using `ln` from `coreutils`, that is)